# NEO4J - RHEL7 - Cannot create constraint on empty DB

Tags: neo4j, cypher, rhel

Deployed NEO4j on a hardened RHEL7 using ansible.
No constraint can be created even though the DB is empty. Any idea on how to debug this or what could be the cause? Other objects can be created. It seems to be a problem with some core library...
We have the same install on another instance which works fine, so I suppose it must be something related to the deployment...even though there were not install errors

Thanks.

Error logs below:

020-07-09 12:11:13.898+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.v.r.ErrorReporter] Client triggered an unexpected error [Neo.DatabaseError.Schema.ConstraintCreationFailed]: Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( equipment:Equipment ) ASSERT equipment.UUID IS UNIQUE:
, reference 0a5adcde-dbeb-4ef0-b9aa-9bf32ef58e63.
2020-07-09 12:11:13.898+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.v.r.ErrorReporter] Client triggered an unexpected error [Neo.DatabaseError.Schema.ConstraintCreationFailed]: Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( equipment:Equipment ) ASSERT equipment.UUID IS UNIQUE:
, reference 0a5adcde-dbeb-4ef0-b9aa-9bf32ef58e63. Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( equipment:Equipment ) ASSERT equipment.UUID IS UNIQUE:

org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionKernelException: Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( equipment:Equipment ) ASSERT equipment.UUID IS UNIQUE:

```
           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachineSPI$1.start(TransactionStateMachineSPI.java:158)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachine$State.startExecution(TransactionStateMachine.java:444)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachine$State$1.execute(TransactionStateMachine.java:259)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachine$State$1.run(TransactionStateMachine.java:240)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachine.run(TransactionStateMachine.java:81)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine$State$2.run(BoltStateMachine.java:457)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.run(BoltStateMachine.java:225)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.BoltMessageRouter.lambda$onRun$3(BoltMessageRouter.java:93)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.MetricsReportingBoltConnection.lambda$enqueue$0(MetricsReportingBoltConnection.java:69)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:195)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.MetricsReportingBoltConnection.processNextBatch(MetricsReportingBoltConnection.java:87)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:143)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.executeBatch(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:170)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.lambda$scheduleBatchOrHandleError$2(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:153)
           at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionKernelException: Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( equipment:Equipment ) ASSERT equipment.UUID IS UNIQUE:

```
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ExecutionEngine.java:65)
           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachineSPI$1.start(TransactionStateMachineSPI.java:144)
           ... 17 more
```

Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.CypherExecutionException: Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( equipment:Equipment ) ASSERT equipment.UUID IS UNIQUE:

```
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.ExceptionTranslationSupport$class.translateException(ExceptionTranslationSupport.scala:35)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:41)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.createUniqueConstraint(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:128)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.runtime.interpreted.UpdateCountingQueryContext.createUniqueConstraint(UpdateCountingQueryContext.scala:125)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.runtime.executionplan.procs.ProcedureCallOrSchemaCommandExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$6.apply(ProcedureCallOrSchemaCommandExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:80)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.runtime.executionplan.procs.ProcedureCallOrSchemaCommandExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$6.apply(ProcedureCallOrSchemaCommandExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:78)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.runtime.executionplan.procs.PureSideEffectExecutionPlan.run(PureSideEffectExecutionPlan.scala:55)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility.scala:128)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility.scala:124)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.exceptionHandler$runSafely$.apply(exceptionHandler.scala:89)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility.scala:124)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.PreparedPlanExecution.execute(PreparedPlanExecution.scala:29)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:119)
           at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ExecutionEngine.java:61)
           ... 18 more
```

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.schema.CreateConstraintFailureException: Unable to create constraint org.neo4j.kernel.api.schema.constaints.UniquenessConstraintDescriptor@6: Existing data does not satisfy CONSTRAINT ON ( label[1]:label[1] ) ASSERT label[1].property[0] IS UNIQUE: Failed to populate index for :Equipment(UUID) [provider: {key=lucene+native, version=2.0}] [labelId: 1, properties [0]]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.newapi.Operations.indexBackedConstraintCreate(Operations.java:1239)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.newapi.Operations.uniquePropertyConstraintCreate(Operations.java:943)
at org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.SchemaWrite.uniquePropertyConstraintCreate(SchemaWrite.java:66)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.runtime.interpreted.TransactionBoundQueryContext.createUniqueConstraint(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:670)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$createUniqueConstraint$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:128)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$createUniqueConstraint$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:128)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$createUniqueConstraint$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:128)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.ExceptionTranslationSupport$class.translateException(ExceptionTranslationSupport.scala:33)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.schema.UniquePropertyValueValidationException: Existing data does not satisfy CONSTRAINT ON ( label[1]:label[1] ) ASSERT label[1].property[0] IS UNIQUE: Failed to populate index for :Equipment(UUID) [provider: {key=lucene+native, version=2.0}] [labelId: 1, properties [0]]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.ConstraintIndexCreator.awaitConstrainIndexPopulation(ConstraintIndexCreator.java:244)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.ConstraintIndexCreator.createUniquenessConstraintIndex(ConstraintIndexCreator.java:135)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.newapi.Operations.indexBackedConstraintCreate(Operations.java:1224)
... 38 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.index.IndexPopulationFailedKernelException: Failed to populate index for :Equipment(UUID) [provider: {key=lucene+native, version=2.0}] [labelId: 1, properties [0]]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexPopulationFailure$1.asIndexPopulationFailure(IndexPopulationFailure.java:47)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.FailedIndexProxy.failureCause(FailedIndexProxy.java:80)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.FailedIndexProxy.awaitStoreScanCompleted(FailedIndexProxy.java:75)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.FlippableIndexProxy.awaitStoreScanCompleted(FlippableIndexProxy.java:325)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.AbstractDelegatingIndexProxy.awaitStoreScanCompleted(AbstractDelegatingIndexProxy.java:122)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.ConstraintIndexCreator.awaitConstrainIndexPopulation(ConstraintIndexCreator.java:232)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter.validateAutoPrefixSettings(II)V
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.autoprefix.AutoPrefixPostingsFormat.(AutoPrefixPostingsFormat.java:77)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.autoprefix.AutoPrefixPostingsFormat.(AutoPrefixPostingsFormat.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:72)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.(NamedSPILoader.java:51)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.(NamedSPILoader.java:38)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat$Holder.(PostingsFormat.java:49)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat.forName(PostingsFormat.java:112)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene62.Lucene62Codec.(Lucene62Codec.java:167)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene62.Lucene62Codec.(Lucene62Codec.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:72)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.(NamedSPILoader.java:51)
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.(NamedSPILoader.java:38)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder.(Codec.java:47)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.getDefault(Codec.java:143)
at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:121)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.(IndexWriterConfig.java:151)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.IndexWriterConfigs.standard(IndexWriterConfigs.java:81)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.IndexWriterConfigs.population(IndexWriterConfigs.java:119)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.IndexWriterConfigs.population(IndexWriterConfigs.java:114)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.partition.WritableIndexPartitionFactory.createPartition(WritableIndexPartitionFactory.java:45)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.AbstractLuceneIndex.open(AbstractLuceneIndex.java:103)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.WritableAbstractDatabaseIndex.open(WritableAbstractDatabaseIndex.java:62)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.schema.populator.LuceneIndexPopulator.create(LuceneIndexPopulator.java:51)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.fusion.InstanceSelector.consume(InstanceSelector.java:147)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.fusion.InstanceSelector.forAll(InstanceSelector.java:90)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.fusion.FusionIndexPopulator.create(FusionIndexPopulator.java:56)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.MultipleIndexPopulator$IndexPopulation.create(MultipleIndexPopulator.java:525)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.MultipleIndexPopulator.lambda$create$0(MultipleIndexPopulator.java:144)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.MultipleIndexPopulator.forEachPopulation(MultipleIndexPopulator.java:408)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.MultipleIndexPopulator.create(MultipleIndexPopulator.java:141)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexPopulationJob.run(IndexPopulationJob.java:103)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexPopulationJobController$IndexPopulationJobWrapper.run(IndexPopulationJobController.java:82)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.scheduler.ThreadPool.lambda$submit$0(ThreadPool.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
... 3 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was a problem with the deployment. A newer lucene library was deployed, one that did not contain that method.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the database might not be empty due to this error:

> Existing data does not satisfy CONSTRAINT ON ( label[1]:label[1] )
> ASSERT label[1].property[0] IS UNIQUE

It complains that the constraint cannot be created as the existing data does not satisfy the constraint.

You can find the culprit with this query:

```
MATCH ( e:Equipment ) 
WITH e.UUID as id, count(*) as count
WHERE count > 1
RETURN id;
```

Comment: Hi Tomaz, The Db is empty, the same error is returned for any newly added constraint. Now I suspect that there is something wrong with a core library...even though it seems ok on the server: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter.validateAutoPrefixSettings(II)V. Thanks for your answer!